# Pandas read csv, trim last two characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas

A csv file looks like this:

```
a,b,c
1,2,3, 
4,5,6, 
a,b,c,
```

When I tried reading this file with pandas read_csv, the data frame looks like this :

```
   |---------------|
   |   | a | b | c |
   |---------------|
   | 1 | 2 | 3 |   |
   | 4 | 5 | 6 |   |
   | a | b | c |   |
   |---------------|
```

I think the problem here in the data is : it looks like 1,2,3,space\n and pandas think there are 4 columns and the first column is unnamed. Is there any way I can change this to :

```
   |-----------|
   | a | b | c |
   |-----------|
   | 1 | 2 | 3 |
   | 4 | 5 | 6 |
   | a | b | c |
   |-----------|
```

These files are around 50 million rows and there are many files. Is there any way to do it with minimal run-time ?

Comment: Look at usecols parameter in pd.read_csv

Comment: @ScottBoston, can you explain a bit more about I could use that in this case ?

Comment: You can use `index_col=False` in `read_csv()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider below code where `index_col=False`. You can use this solution when you do not know how many columns are expected in the csv file. Better if different files have different number of columns. Refer to [Docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) for more information.

```
from io import StringIO
csvtext = StringIO("""a,b,c
1,2,3, 
4,5,6, 
a,b,c, """)

df = pd.read_csv(csvtext, index_col=False)
df
```

Output:

```
    a   b   c
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6
2   a   b   c
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `usecol` parameter in `pd.read_csv` to read only the first three columns in the csv file.

```
from io import StringIO
csvtext = StringIO("""a,b,c
1,2,3, 
4,5,6, 
a,b,c, """)

df = pd.read_csv(csvtext, usecols=[0,1,2])
df
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  a  b  c
```

Comment: How can I use it, if I don't know how many columns are there in the input csv file? I have large number of files and can't manually check how many columns are there in that file.

Comment: You are correct. You should try @harvipan solution.

Comment: Yes, I will do. Thanks @Scott, your solution also worked.